# statfs attempting large write causing stack overflow

Tags: c, linux, macos, stack-overflow, system-calls

I'm currently using `statfs` to get some information about a path and I'm getting a runtime stack overflow error:

```
==33949==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x000103d3d970 at pc 0x00010172b930 bp 0x00016fdfeed0 sp 0x00016fdfe688
WRITE of size 2168 at 0x000103d3d970 thread T0
    #0 0x10172b92c in wrap_statfs+0x2ac (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64e+0x2b92c)
    #1 0x107a10ccc in StatFsErr() OtherFile.c:546
    #2 0x1000c3318 in main main.cpp:141
    #3 0x193d43f24  (<unknown module>)

Address 0x000103d3d970 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 368 in frame
    #0 0x107a10a64 in StatFsErr() OtherFile.c:538

  This frame has 2 object(s):
    [32, 368) 'sb' (line 541)
    [432, 1457) 'path' (line 542) <== Memory access at offset 368 partially underflows this variable
```

My code looks like this:

### OtherFile.c:

```
void StatFsErr()
{
  struct statfs sb;
  char path[PATH_MAX + 1];
  memset(path, 0, sizeof(path));
  path[0] = '/';
  OSStatus    err = statfs(path, &sb);
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "OtherFile.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  StatFsErr();
  return 0;
}
```

Curiously, I do not get any exceptions if I move the body of StatFsErr() to main(), ie.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct statfs sb;
  char path[PATH_MAX + 1];
  memset(path, 0, sizeof(path));
  path[0] = '/';
  OSStatus    err = statfs(path, &sb);
  return 0;
}
```

While I imagine that some kind of stack overflow is at play here, I don't see why `statfs` would attempt such a large write. From what I understand of the Linux reference for `statfs`, it simply returns information about the file at `path` in `sb`, which appears to sit comfortably on the stack.

I can see that this issue appears to be resolvable if I do

```
char sb_buf [2200];
char path[PATH_MAX + 1];
memset(path, 0, sizeof(path));
path[0] = '/';
OSStatus    err = statfs(path, (struct statfs *)sb_buf);
```

but it doesn't help me see why `statfs` appears to write beyond the size of `sb`.

Can anyone enlighten me on what is happening?

Thanks!!

## Update:

Following President James K. Polk's suggestion, I found that the issue was caused by having compiled 'OtherFile.c' with '-D__DARWIN_64_BIT_INO_T=0'. A minimal reproducible example would then be

### main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct statfs sb;
  char path[PATH_MAX + 1] = "/";
  OSStatus    err = statfs(path, &sb);
  return 0;
}
```

and compiling `main.cpp` with `-D__DARWIN_64_BIT_INO_T=0`, which produces the corresponding error message:

```
=================================================================
==36752==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x000103cb1170 at pc 0x00010169f930 bp 0x00016fdff0b0 sp 0x00016fdfe868
WRITE of size 2168 at 0x000103cb1170 thread T0
    #0 0x10169f92c in wrap_statfs+0x2ac (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64e+0x2b92c)
    #1 0x1000bc880 in main main.cpp:11
    #2 0x193d43f24  (<unknown module>)

Address 0x000103cb1170 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 368 in frame
    #0 0x1000bc604 in main main.cpp:5

  This frame has 2 object(s):
    [32, 368) 'sb' (line 7)
    [432, 1457) 'path' (line 8) <== Memory access at offset 368 partially underflows this variable
```

I imagine that since [APFS uses 64-bit inodes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/fsref), the macOS kernel returns the 64-bit version of `struct statfs` defined in `mount.h` which is 2168 bytes large and which causes the overflow.

Can someone confirm it that's the case?

Comment: Which is line 540? There must be a lot more to the code than the dozen or so lines shown. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem.

Comment: I replaced `OSStatus` with `int` and added the needed `#include` lines, and it runs fine on my Mac.

Comment: I'd guess that you're pulling in a definition for `struct statfs` that makes sense for linux but actually running it on MacOS. This question really needs a [mre].

Comment: `struct statfs` is 120 bytes on my linux.  What made you allocate 2200 bytes for `sb_buf`?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner, Aside: `char path[PATH_MAX + 1]; memset(path, 0, sizeof(path));` simpler and clearer with `char path[PATH_MAX + 1] = { 0 };` or `char path[PATH_MAX + 1] = "";`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: And the next line can go away too, with `char path[PATH_MAX + 1] = { '/' };`

Comment: @BenVoigt, yours is even better! Another idea: `char path[PATH_MAX + 1] = "/";`

Comment: @TedLyngmo: On Mac, `f_mntonname` and `f_mntfromname` are 90 bytes each, so definitely more than 120 total.

Comment: @BenVoigt Those don't even exist in the linux version of `struct statfs`. Perhaps PresidentJamesK.Polk is correct when guessing that OP has copied a linux header and uses that on a mac.